# how to localize the app strings

Tags: dart, flutter

In Android, I've 2 string values for localization:

1. values / strings.xml => `<string name="ok">OK</string>`
2. values / strings.xml (es) => `<string name="ok">DE ACUERDO</string>`

and I'm accessing them through:

```
R.string.ok
```

As Android take care for localization as per these files.

How can I do the same in `Flutter`, can I use something equivalent to `R.string.ok` and how? is it possible for both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [flutter internationalization tutorial](https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/) will do a better job of explaining than I will; the TLDR is that you define a class that returns the various strings for different locales and use Localizations.of to get ahold of it.

This isn't quite the same as `R.string.ok`; to get something with that level of ease-of-use, you'll need to use the [intl](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl) package which automates most of it. See [this example](https://github.com/flutter/website/tree/master/_includes/code/internationalization/intl/) which is described in the internaitionalization tutorial. But you can write your own code to do that if intl doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ (Android Studio), you can use the [Flutter i18n](https://github.com/long1eu/flutter_i18n) plugin.